# Should I include AR, MA, or ARMA in my DCC(1,1)GARCH(1,1) approach?

Tags: time-series, arima, modeling, garch, volatility-forecasting

I know an AR, MA or generally speaking an ARMA term is included for the mean. I however can not find how to determine this for my specific application. Is there any information that can be derived from my test results that indicate what I should use for the model? I lack information to interpret my results regarding this aspect. Here are the R outputs:
[image: Text]
[image: Text]
[image: Text]

Does it even matter if my main interest is the conditional correlations, thus dcca1 and dccb1? Some indications if my model is appropriately fitted would also really be appreciated! Should I test this too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimality of modelling decisions depends on the ultimate goal (description, forecasting, causal analysis, etc.).

For **description**, you would usually want your model to be a statistically adequate description of the data generating process. I.e. you would like the data to satisfy the assumptions of the model, as otherwise you cannot interpret your findings in the usual way. In (ARMA)-GARCH-DCC this means your standardized innovations should be i.i.d. with zero mean and unit variance. If your dependent variable $y_t$ exhibits zero autocorrelation, a GARCH-DCC model may be just fine. However, if your dependent variable $y_t$ exhibits nonzero autocorrelation at some lag(s), a pure GARCH-DCC model will not be able to account for it; then your standardized innovations will have nonzero autocorrelation and thus violate the assumption of being i.i.d. Therefore, you may want to include an ARMA equation for the conditional mean of $y_t$. Whether it should be pure AR, pure MA or full ARMA depends on the properties of the data generating process; I use ARMA as the general term.

For **forecasting**, you may choose to ignore the fact that some assumptions are violated if fixing that decreases forecast accuracy. E.g. if you include an ARMA equation but are not able to estimate the parameters accurately enough, your forecasts might be worse than without ARMA -- even if there is genuine autocorrelation in your data generating process. You need to try it both ways (with and without ARMA) and see which model provides the most accurate forecasts.

I will skip the case of causal analysis for now.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. I'm using it as a description. I read about Ljung-Box, is that applicable here to help confirm the autocorrelation is properly captured? 

With your expert eye, does this model look like it's properly fitted? Judging by the parameters and the joint estimations. I'm just starting with figuring out the full interpretation, so any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @garchbeginner, just looking at the size and significance of model coefficients does not tell you much. You should be more interested in seeing diagnostic measures and tests of standardized innovations (standardized residuals). Autocorrelation in levels and squares within a series as well as across series would be some relevant things to look at. Simply put, one should be looking at whether the model's assumptions are met. There are usually no assumptions about the size or significance of coefficients.